# Network pop up not showing up

Tags: javascript, tizen

I have a tizen tv app and a pop up should appear when the internet is lost and dissapear when it comes back but the message never appears. i have 2 js files videoplayer and main.js i tried adding the code to one of them them both then tried index.html too but no luck. How can i correctly add this features so it works? This is my index.html without any pop up code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
  content="width=1920">
<title>REDACTED</title>
<!-- <script type='text/javascript' src='$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js'></script> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link href="lib/videojs/v6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- <link href="lib/videojsPlugin/record/css/videojs.record.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<link href="lib/videojsPlugin/thumbnails/videojs-vtt-thumbnails.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- <link href="lib/videojsPlugin/bitrategraph/videojs-bitrate-graph.css" 
rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>
<body>

<div class="left">
    <h2></h2>
    <div>
    </div>
    <fieldset id="logsFieldset">
        <legend>Logs</legend>
        <div class="logs" id="logs"></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <h2></h2>

    <button id="setfullscreen" left="videojsContainner"></button>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Video info</legend>
        <div class="logs" id="info"></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
<!--<script src="lib/videojs/v5/video.min.js"></script>-->
<!-- <script src="lib/videojsPlugin/hlsvideojs5-hlsjs-source-handler.min.js"></script> 
<script src="lib/videojsPlugin/hls/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/videojs/v6/video.js"></script>
<script src="lib/videojsPlugin/hls/hls.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/videojsPlugin/hls/videojs-hlsjs.js"></script>
<script>window.HELP_IMPROVE_VIDEOJS = false;</script>
<script src="lib/videojsPlugin/hotkey/videojs.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script src="lib/videojsPlugin/playlist/videojs-playlist.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/videojsPlugin/thumbnails/videojs-vtt-thumbnails.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="lib/videojsPlugin/record/depend/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="lib/videojsPlugin/record/depend/webrtc-adapter.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="lib/videojsPlugin/snapshot/shoot.js"></script>
<script src="lib/videojsPlugin/record/videojs.record.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="lib/videojsPlugin/bitrategraph/videojs-bitrate-graph.min.js"></script>        -->
<script src="js/videoJSPlayer.js"></script>
<script src="js/videoPlayer.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```